# ¿Como puedo saber los tipos de estado de una conexion wifi?

Tags: android

Quiero saber si cuando hago wifiManager.reconnect() el se conecta o no... Por ejemplo si es una red WPA y pongo la contraseña mal a proposito, y se ejecuta wifiManager.reconnect me devuelve true. Como puedo saber si me conecte, si me da error, si se esta conectando? Gracias

Comment: Lo más práctico es que registres un broadcast receiver sobre el cambio de estado del wifimanager (con WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) Si solo necesitas asegurarte de que la conexión se ha realizado (y luego olvidarte) asegúrate de "desregistrarlo" una vez conecte.

Comment: explicame mejor se lo que me dices y por intuicion lo hice pero no se en que parte del codigo el broadcast reciever llamarlo...Tienes algun codigo?

Comment: Aquí puedes seguir la guía de google sobre [broadcastreceivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html)

Te recomiendo que uses uno registrado dinámicamente (context-registered receivers) usando como la acción por la que filtrar.